# Kiel diri "close-up" aŭ "zoom in"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi serĉis en reta vortaro, sed nenion trovis. 
Mi pensis pri kaj versioj de "alproksimiĝaĵo" kaj "pligrandiĝo", "detalaĵo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eble *unua plano* aŭ *ekstra plano* taŭgas por tio. El [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#plano):

> * **plan/o**
>   **4** Ĉiu parto de filmo, kiu estis fotita sen lokŝanĝo de la kamerao, k povas daŭri de unu sekundo ĝis pluraj minutoj: *la plano estas en filmo tio, kio estas la frazo en romano*; *plano fora* (ĝenerala perspektivo), *meza* (la personoj sen konsidero pri la dekoracio), *proksima* (la personoj ĝistalie), *unua* (la vizaĝo), *ekstra* (nur unu detalo).

Tio tamen estas teĥnika termino. Alie, eble *zomaĵo* taŭgas, sed mi ne trovis tiun vorton ie. [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=close-up) donas *deproksima foto* kaj *detalbildo*.

Answer (score -1):

Se temas pri ekz. bildojn, oni diras "pligrandigi bildon" kaj male "malpligrandigi bildon".

Vidu [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#pligrandigi)-on kaj serĉu vorton "pligrandigi" en [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php).

Comment: Bonvenon al StackExchange :)! La demandanto petas terminon por la speco de tia foto, ne por la ago _zomi_ aŭ _(mal)pligrandigi foton_. De ŝia demando oni povas inferenci, ke ŝi jam konscias pri ĉi tiu vorto ;).

Comment: @Joffysloffy Dankon! Se oni scias la verbon por la ago, oni povas formi terminon por la rezulto per uzo de participo. Do _(mal)pligrandigita foto_.

Comment: Nedankinde! Prave, ofte jes, sed ne ĉiam: _pligrandigita foto_ ne nepre estas ‘close-up’, ĉar mi povas fari iun ajn foton kaj produkti pli grandan ekzempleron sur ekrano aŭ papero, kiu tiam estas pligrandigita foto, sed ne ‘close-up’ ;).

Comment: Dankon pro la respondo! Jes, mi pripensis ion similan al "pligandigaĵo", kion vi povas vidi en la teksto de mia demando. Ne ĉiam facilas trovi la ĝustan vorton. Estas multaj ebloj.